# gcc g++ 4.7 install on suse never found the "rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma)

Tags: opensuse, suse, gcc4.9, g++-4.7

I found the rpm by google
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20369594/dir/opensuse_12.x/com/gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64.rpm.html

```
# wget ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/opensuse/distribution/12.3/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -ivh gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64.rpm
```

```
# error: Failed dependencies:

gcc47 = 4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6 is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libcloog.so.0()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libgmp.so.10()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libgmpxx.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libmpc.so.3()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libppl.so.9()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libppl_c.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
libstdc++47-devel = 4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6 is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by gcc47-c++-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64
```

I found the rpm one by one, but I never found the "rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1"
so I try to use another method to install GCC g++ 4.7

```
# zypper sl
# | Enabled | Refresh | Type | Name                                | URI                                      
--+---------+---------+------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
1 | Yes     | No      | YaST | SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP1 | cd:///?devices=/dev/sr0                  
2 | Yes     | Yes     | YUM  | main                                | http://download.opensuse.org/update/11.1/

# zypper install gcc
Restoring system sources...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP1...
Parsing metadata for main...
Parsing RPM database...
skipping package 'gcc' (already installed)
Summary:
Nothing to do.

# zypper install g++
Restoring system sources...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP1...
Parsing metadata for main...
Parsing RPM database...
package 'g++' not found
Summary:
Nothing to do.
```

```
zypper install gcc49
Restoring system sources...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP1...
Parsing metadata for main...
Parsing metadata for http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/...
Parsing RPM database...
Problems:
PROB gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64[http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/] cannot be installed due to missing dependencies
:    There are no installable providers of cpp49 == 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 for gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64[http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/]
 SOL  do not install gcc49
 :    do not install gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64[http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/]
 SOL  Ignore this requirement just here
 :    
Summary:
<install>   [S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
Continue? [y/n] y
Downloading: [S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64, 11.6 M(54.7 M unpacked)
Installing: [S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
[S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64 Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: Failed dependencies:
        cpp49 = 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libasan1 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libatomic1 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libcilkrts5 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libcloog-isl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libgcc_s1 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libgmp.so.10()(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libgomp1 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libisl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libitm1 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        liblsan0 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libmpc.so.3()(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libtsan0 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        libubsan0 >= 4.9.2+r218474-52.1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64


Invalid object
Invalid object
Installing: [S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
[S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64 Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic


(with nodeps)Invalid object
(with nodeps)Invalid object
Installing: [S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64
[S3:0][package]gcc49-4.9.2+r218474-52.1.x86_64 Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic


(with nodeps+force)Invalid object
(A)bort, (R)etry, (I)gnore?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.0/gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.9.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd .. 
cd gcc-build-4.9.0
../gcc-4.9.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
make -j4  (wait for 40 min)
make install
```